# Is any web-working autopost tool for Instagram which allows adding several photos per post?

Tags: instagram

I am looking for web-working auto post tool for Instagram which allows adding several photos per post. Free or paid. Can you recommend one?

All apps I have found, makes Instagram post with only 1 picture per post. But I need up to 10 pictures in one post.

I need to publish 5-10 post per day. Each post will have up to 10 pictures of items we sell. 
I need this tool because we work using PC, not tablets, not smartphones. So we can not use Instagram directly. 
We don't need scheduler option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried any of those but here are two options from internetmarketingninjas.com

**Schedugram**

> Just want something super simple that schedules and auto-posts photos
>   and videos, then lets you know? Then this one might be for you. Upload
>   via you browser, manage multiple accounts, and allow multiple
>   administrators access. Once the scheduled posts have been published,
>   you get an emailed alert. So any time there it a problem, you will
>   know right away.
>
> Best of all, there is multiple upload support. So you can put a bunch
>   of photos or videos on at once, edit the information like meta data,
>   and then schedule them all at once. This is so much more efficient
>   than doing it one by one.

[Schedugram homepage](http://schedugr.am/)

[image: Schedugram screenshot]

---

**Latergram**

> The idea is pretty simple. You upload one or multiple images/videos
>   from either the web or phone. You set a schedule so they are released
>   as you want them to be. You can then get the images pushed to your
>   phone, if you choose. You will get an alert just prior to scheduled
>   posts publishing, so you can either change/erase the post, or verify
>   it.
>
> Because you have to authorize the publishing at the time it is
>   scheduled, this is more a way of monitoring your posting calender than
>   an autoposter. But for those who want more control, it is a great
>   tool.

[More info about Latergram](https://later.com/blog/auto-publish-instagram/)

[image: Latergram screenshot]

**EDIT:** Source: [Instagram schedulers with description](https://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/social-media/schedule-instagram-updates-post-instagram-web/)